# Java XPath - find tags prefixed with

Tags: java, parsing, xpath

I have a following HTML

```
<data-my-tag>
  <data-another-tag>
    ... content ... 
  </data-another-tag>
  <data-my-tag>
    ... content ... 
  </data-my-tag>
</data-my-tag>
```

Now I need to find all tags starting with prefix `<data-`. I need to find their names and also their contents. I know this is not possible to achieve with regex, so I started to work with `javax.xml.parsers`. It is easy for me to find some tags according to a particular name, but I am unable to find tags starting with some prefix.

What is the expression or code to find tags starting with prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath's [starts-with](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-starts-with) function:

```
public void findElements(InputSource source,
                         String prefix) {

    try {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        NodeList matches = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(
            "//*[starts-with(local-name(), '" + prefix + "')]",
            source, XPathConstants.NODESET);

        int count = matches.getLength();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            Node match = matches.item(i);
            System.out.println("Element: " + match.getNodeName());
            System.out.println("Text: " + match.getTextContent().trim());
            System.out.println();
        }
    } catch (XPathException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can we use something like this :

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import java.io.File;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File inputFile = new File("input.txt");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE || nNode.getNodeName().startsWith("<data-")) {
                    System.out.println(nNode.getTextContent());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```